# Parse the content of a file and store in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a test file 'templates.txt' which I am loading it through an ajax call.

The content of the text file is in this format.

```
{template templateA}
    templateA content
{/template}

{template templateB}   
    templateB content
{/template}

{template templateC}   
    templateC content
{/template}
```

When I load it through an ajax I get the content of the whole file as a string.
Lets assume I have the content of the file in the variable templateContent.

```
var templateContent = myFileContent;
```

But I want to parse this string variable and convert it into an object as follows.

```
{ 
   templateA : templateA content,
   templateB : templateB content,
   templateC : templateC content
}
```

How can I do it in javascript? Can regex be a good option?

NOTE : There is requirement for this format. Even Google Closure templates uses the same format. https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js

Comment: Why you don't build the content of the file in JSON format?

Comment: Is there a reaon that your template file is in that weird format? Could you not just format it as JSON?

Comment: @Moob The format is not weird. There is a requirement. Even google closure templates uses the same format. Check out the link https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not how I'd go about it but if you *have* to use that 'weird' format you could use a RegEx to split it into parts:

```
/{template (.*?)}(.*?)\{\/template\}/g
```

Note, this assumes you've stripped the new-lines from the template string but you could adapt the expression as required. [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sM5lU7/1) is great for testing your expressions.

```js
var obj = {},
    str = "{template templateA}templateA content{/template}{template templateB}templateB content{/template}{template templateC}templateC content{/template}",
    rx = /{template (.*?)}(.*?)\{\/template\}/g,
    item;

while (item = rx.exec(str))
    obj[item[1]] = item[2];

console.log(obj);
alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); //outputs {"templateA":"templateA content","templateB":"templateB content","templateC":"templateC content"}
```